# Canonical module of a Buchsbaum ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Is the canonical module of a Buchsbaum ring a Buchsbaum module?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. I don't know how this is not research level mathematics. And I'd really like to hear someone explain why they voted to close it for that reason. Yes, it's not very detailed, but most likely that is due more to a limitation in English than in math. In my own research I have recently wondered about this same question and that's how I knew the answer. There are many inappropriate questions on MO, but this is not one of those. In fact, I'd say this is exactly the type of question why MO was originally started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See Theorem 4.9 on page 138 of [Buchsbaum Rings and Applications](https://books.google.com/books?id=iVHooQEACAAJ) by Jürgen Stückrad and Wolfgang Vogel.